# Changing to a specific directory in an easier manner

Tags: command-line, 20.04, cd

Whenever I want to start coding, I have to `cd` to `Desktop/Programming/C++`, whereas I am looking for an easier manner to do so, more precisely I am looking for a terminal command which will automatically `cd` to that specific directory. Can I create such a command in terminal? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write this assuming you don't know much about Ubuntu - please accept my apologies if it's too straightforward.

Absolutely you can. You need to create an alias.
Pick a name for the command you want to alias to the command you want executed. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and type it to check it is not currently assigned to something.

So let's say you want to use the command `prog` to move to that directory, you can make it temporarily happen by creating an alias for your absolute path to the directory you want. Open a terminal and type

```
alias prog="cd /home/user/Desktop/Programming/C++"
```

(obviously you'll need to put in the correct path to your target folder; do note it has to be an absolute path not a relative one).

Then, within that terminal session, every time you type `prog` it will execute the `cd /home/user/Desktop/Programming/C++` command.

Note that this will only work during that terminal session. To make it permanent, you'll need to edit the `.bashrc` file:

You need to be comfortable editing text configuration files.

I’m not personally comfortable using Vi / Vim – but nano is pretty straightforward.

It involves editing `.bashrc` which is in your home directory.

This is, I think, pretty safe, even if you're not very familiar with editing such files:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Go to your home directory with `cd ~`
3. Confirm `.bashrc` is there with `ls -a`
4. Assuming it is, first create a backup copy of it so you can undo it if you mess it up completely:

   ```
    cp .bashrc .bashrc-bak
   ```

   (if you cause a problem you can reinstate the original `.bashrc` file by typing `cp .bashrc-bak .bashrc`)
5. Now you can edit `.bashrc` knowing there is a safe copy:

   Type `nano .bashrc` (or you can use an alternative text editor if you prefer)

   This opens `.bashrc` in the text editor.

Whilst you can add the lines anywhere, it makes sense for future editing to find a space where there are some aliases and add yours below the ones there:

```
alias prog=”cd /home/user/Desktop/Programming/C++”
```

Then save the file by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, and exit nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.
If you make a mistake, if you can't undo it, exit nano (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>X) without saving and start again.

The change will take effect as soon as you either start a new terminal session, or type  `. ~/.bashrc` (note the `.` at the beginning!).

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities.

• In first instance, you could maintain aliases that bring you to specific folders, e.g

`alias cdplus='cd Desktop/Programming/C++'`

The command `cdplus` will then bring you in that directory.

• Alternatively, you can make use of the CDPATH variable. In such variable, you include directories in which the `cd` command will search for matching folders, so you do not have to type the full path. e.g. if you define

```
CDPATH=".:Desktop/Programming"
```

you will be able to `cd C++` (and any other folder under `Programming`) irrespective of your current directory. The first entry, `.`, means the current folder, so you can keep `cd`ing into a folder in the current folder.

• Third party tools exist for fast directory navigation, such as [`goto`](https://github.com/iridakos/goto), which work in a similar way as with aliases, but keeps these definitions apart. You could also use fuzzy finder (`fzf`, `sudo apt install fzf`). On Ubuntu, a bash shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> ("Current directory") is automatically set up to quickly navigate to any directory under the current folder. You get a list of all directories that quickly narrows down as you type parts of the name. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> bring you in that directory.

• A tool like [`autojump`](https://github.com/wting/autojump) (`sudo apt install autojump`) registers the directories you visit, and allows you to revisit them quicky just by typing their name after the `autojump` command. This tool "learns" from your current useage, without a need to maintain a list. An alternative is [Shonejump](https://github.com/suzaku/shonenjump), a rewrite in the programming language "Go".